# Restore Purchases button for In App Purchases stored on website?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

Is a Restore Purchases button that calls restoreCompletedTransactions needed for In App Purchased consumables and non-auto renewable subscriptions if the current user's count of these purchases is stored and retrieved from a website?

I'm thinking the Restore Purchases button is not needed in this case.  In my app whenever the user wants to use an In App Purchased consumable or subscription, the app contacts the website and downloads the user's current count of the In App Purchased consumable/subscription.  These In App Purchased products can only be used with internet connectivity, so if there is no Internet access, then the user can't use the In App Purchased consumable/subscription.

I understand the case where a user has multiple devices and has In App Purchased consumable/subscriptions that were purchased on one device and wants to use these products on another device, but that is not the case I am asking about here.

Is a Restore Purchases button needed where the In App Purchased items are stored on a website and the In App Purchased items are used on the same device that they were purchased on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think,that if you store all the history of user purchases,and you will let him use all the purchases he made right when he wants it,there is no need for an extra Restore button in your app.